# Can you identify this LEGO space set?

Tags: set-identification, space

I've just purchased a random box of Star Wars LEGO at a car boot sale and there's a few bits in there that I'd like to identify the set for.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a Star Wars set, it's most of the main part from "[70704 Vermin Vaporizer](https://brickset.com/sets/70704-1/Vermin-Vaporizer)" from the Galaxy Squad theme.

The word "pressure" on the green tile hints that it's not Star Wars, as that would normally be in Aurebesh - the written script you see in the films.

It turns out the curved white roof tile ([Circle 90G 6X6 Roof Tile](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6001926)) at the front was only used in three sets, which helps identify it.

Comment: This would actually not be a bad set to re-purpose as an APC for a Star Wars setup. You wouldn't necessarily need to remove the word - Roman script actually appears in the Star Wars universe as a rare-ish alphabet known as "High Galactic". Come up with your own story as to why the builders of this vehicle or the faction that configured it used that script.